# Does the navigationController.viewControllers do not include viewControllers that were presented modally?

Tags: ios, swift

I presented a viewController modally and was expecting it to show up when I accessed the `navigationController.viewControllers`. Is it the expected behavior, that viewControllers presented modally using the same navigationController will not be included in the `navigationController.viewControllers` array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Presented ViewControllers are not in navigation view hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is the desired behaviour. The `viewControllers` property will return the view-controllers that are available in the navigation stack.

Refer [viewControllers](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationcontroller/1621873-viewcontrollers) for more details.

If you want to get the currently visible view-controller regardless whether it's presented modally or pushed, you can use the [visibleViewController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationcontroller/1621862-visibleviewcontroller) property.

```
let visibleVC = navigationController.visibleViewController
```